# OpenGL 3.2 context on a Carbon window (OS Lion, Mono)

Tags: macos, opengl, osx-lion, macos-carbon, cglayer

I'm trying to add modern OS X support to [OpenTK framework](http://opentk.com).
Mac OS Lion supports OpenGL 3.2 Core context. I can successfully obtain it by using [CGL](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_pixelformats/opengl_pixelformats.html). However, I can't find a straight way to bind the context to a Carbon window.

Previous OpenTK implementation used `aglSetDrawable` method. CGL doesn't publicly have an alternative, even though it has a similar [undocumented CGLSetSurface](http://vchannel.sourceforge.net/hacks.html). Any attempts to use it return error code 1001, which I can't find a description for.

Any help of getting GL 3.2 on a Carbon window?

Comment: I haven't worked with lion yet, and also not with opengl 3.2 context. anyways the common way to set the context in CGL is CGLSetCurrentContext. Maybe that works?

Comment: @moka. The context itself is OK. The question is about attaching it to a window without using Cocoa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say I have tried this, but you might be able to get it to work by using a HICocoaView containing an NSOpenGLView (which will take an NSOpenGLContext that can be created froma CGLContext).

AGL itself is deprecated and unlikely to receive any further updates from Apple. CGL is not intended for windowed contexts. In the long run, using Cocoa is the best route on OS X.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Stefan. I understand that Cocoa is the preferred choice now. However, I need to access these functions from Mono, so Objective-C signals are really difficult way to go. It would help if someone had a library for managing NSOpenGLView context with a simple C interface....

Comment: You can wrap Objective-C code in C++ classes, that's what wxWidgets or Qt do. A HICocoaView has a plain C interface already so you would only need to wrap a handful of calls to NSOpenGLView.

Comment: Is AGL as a whole actually deprecated? I noticed parts of it are deprecated in 10.7, but aside from that there's nothing...

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, Apple does not provide any "official" API to bind a CGL context to a view without going through the NSOpenGLContext intermediary (you don't even need to create a full NSOpenGLLView, all you need is the NSOpenGLContext which you can bind to any NSView of your choice). If you just want to get things working, that is the best approach.

Now if you're interested in the undocumented way, buckle up: First, the only official way Apple gives you to bind the FBO to a screen is via CGLSetFullScreenOnDisplay(), as someone mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/53878). But that's not the end of the story. As you noted there is a `CGLSetSurface`, and internally XQuartz uses this (via the libXplugin library that Apple provides) to bind an opengl context directly to a CGWindow without any cocoa machinery getting in the way. As mentioned in this [mailing list thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/xquartz-dev@lists.macosforge.org/msg01057.html)

We can also learn more about the parameters it takes from [this post](https://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/xquartz-dev/2021-February/004117.html).

> Ok, well xp_attach_gl_context is just a wrapper around CGLSetSurface(), which is an internal function to do exactly what we're trying to do here.  If it returns any error, xp_attach_gl_context returns bad value.

> CGLSetSurface just takes a context, connection id, window ID, and
> surface ID.
>
> The context is passed straight from the input to xp_attach_gl_context,
> and the xp_surface_id input to xp_attach_gl_context maps to the wid /
> sid passed to CGLSetSurface.

Luckily others have already done some reverse-engineering for us. You can see in [RetroArch drivers](https://github.com/m4xw/RetroArch_LibNX/blob/master/gfx/drivers_context/cgl_ctx.c#L273) that they make use of this as follows:

```
static CGSSurfaceID attach_gl_context_to_window(CGLContextObj glCtx,
   CGSWindowID wid, int *width, int *height)
{
    CFArrayRef wins;
    CFDictionaryRef win, bnd;
    GLint params = 0;
    Float64 w = 0, h = 0;
    CGSSurfaceID sid = 0;
    CGSConnectionID cid = CGSMainConnectionID();

    printf("cid:%d wid:%d\n", cid, wid);

    /* determine window size */
    /* FIXME/TODO - CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo was introduced on OSX 10.5,
     * find alternative for lower versions. */
    wins = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionIncludingWindow, wid); /* expect one result only */
    win = (CFDictionaryRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(wins, 0);
    bnd = (CFDictionaryRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(win, kCGWindowBounds);
    CFNumberGetValue((CFNumberRef)CFDictionaryGetValue((CFDictionaryRef)bnd, CFSTR("Width")),
       kCFNumberFloat64Type, &w);
    CFNumberGetValue((CFNumberRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(bnd, CFSTR("Height")),
       kCFNumberFloat64Type, &h);
    CFRelease(wins);

    /* create a surface. */
    if(CGSAddSurface(cid, wid, &sid) != kCGErrorSuccess)
    {
       printf("ERR: no surface\n");
    }
    printf("sid:%d\n", sid);

    /* set surface size, and order it frontmost */
    if(CGSSetSurfaceBounds(cid, wid, sid, CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h)) != kCGErrorSuccess)
       printf("ERR: cant set bounds\n");
    if(CGSOrderSurface(cid, wid, sid, 1, 0) != kCGErrorSuccess)
       printf("ERR: cant order front\n");

    /* attach context to the surface */
    if(CGLSetSurface(glCtx, cid, wid, sid) != kCGErrorSuccess)
    {
       printf("ERR: cant set surface\n");
    }

    /* check drawable */
    CGLGetParameter(glCtx, kCGLCPHasDrawable, &params);
    if(params != 1)
    {
       printf("ERR: no drawable\n");
    }

    *width  = (int)w;
    *height = (int)h;

    return sid;
}
```

and another person independently discovered the same in https://handmade.network/forums/wip/t/2408-very_minimal_osx_platform_layer_experiments.

But be aware that when you things like this, you lose a lot of the benefits that the Cocoa layer gives you. Things like hiDPI scaling no longer "just work", and if OpenGL on modern macOS wasn't unsupported enough, bypassing the Cocoa layer is surely going to break whatever assumptions Apple made for their compatibility layer.

Comment: Also found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523777/opengl-on-mac-operation which has an example